# Rails Update More Effiecient

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to update all my entries every 5 minutes.  I am using Rails version 4.2.5 and Ruby version 2.3.0.  My code below has worked fine with a small number of entries.  I have about 800 entries now and it is taking up to 2 minutes to update.  Is there a more efficient way?

```
  @players = Entry.all
  for player in @players
    sort = 0
    @player_selection = Selection.includes(:golfer).where("entry_id = ?", player.id).order('golfers.score asc').all
    for selection in @player_selection
      sort += 1
      score_sort = Selection.where("id = ?", selection.id).first
      score_sort.sort = sort
      score_sort.save
      player = Entry.where("id = ?", selection.entry_id).first
      player.score = Selection.includes(:golfer).where("entry_id = ? and selections.sort < 6", selection.entry_id).sum('golfers.score')
      player.save
    end
  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you could offload some of your work to when records are created and/or updated (instead of aggregating them on a schedule).

e.g. something like:

```
# I assume your relationship is something like this:

class Golfer
  belongs_to :entry
  after_create :update_scores
  after_update :update_scores

  private

  def update_scores
    entry.update(score: entry.golphers.sum(:score))
  end
end
```

This will reduce the workload when you run your sort update process.
Then your sort update process could be streamlined:

```
@entries = Entry.all
@entries.each do |entry|
  sort = 0
  @selections = Selection.includes(:golfer).where("entry_id = ?", player.id).order('golfers.score asc')
  @selections.each do |selection|
    sort += 1
    selection.update(sort: sort)
  end
end
```

by removing the extraneous data request, this will slightly improve the operation.  However, your current operations are going to be linear at-best because you are running it as loop: (O)n + 1 runtime.  You would likely have to drop into SQL to have a significantly faster computation:

```
# -> SQL; depends on DB a bit
UPDATE selections s
s.sort = ns.new_sort
FROM 
(SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score ASC) AS new_sort 
from selection) as nt
```

you could run a pure SQL command using Rails, as such:

```
# Be careful, this is dangerous
sql = "UPDATE ... your sql query here"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```